# SQL - Informix - Changing the datatype of a column from numeric to character

Tags: sql, types, informix, alter

I have a temp table that has numeric integer values in one column.  I want to either replace the integer values with character values based on some criteria or I want to add another column of character type that automatically inserts values into itself based on some criteria.

If x <= 1, change to "SP" or make new column and store "SP" in that row
If x > 1, change to "FA" or make new column and store "FA" in that row
Also, alter commands are not allowed on temp tables in my version of Informix.

Comment: It helps to specify the version of IDS - or other Informix database server - especially if you have to mention 'in my version'.

Comment: i didn't have to mention that, i don't think - how do i get the version? no one seems to know it, and the manuals we have are out of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT id, yr,  CASE WHEN yr_offset <= 1 THEN "SP" ELSE "FA" END CASE

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls909.htm

Comment: cool that worked too... but i had to obviously specify the "from" section after the end case - not your fault, i never mentioned the name of the temp table i was trying to condition

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, you cannot alter a temp table. Adding an extra column with this derived value can be done with a `CASE` statement, ie:

```
SELECT enroll.ud, enroll.yr, (CASE
   WHEN enrollsess.yr_offset <=1 THEN "FA"
   ELSE "SP" END)::CHAR(2) AS sess, ...
```

The casting (ie the parentheses and `::CHAR(2)`) are probably not necessary.

If the logic can be expressed as zero/non-zero (it's not clear in your example if yr_offset can be negative), then it's even simpler:

```
SELECT enroll.id, enroll.yr,
     DECODE(enrollsess.yr_offset, 0, "FA", "SP")::CHAR(2) AS sess, ...
```

[More details on CASE syntax from the manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls909.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT          enrollsess.id,
                enrollsess.yr,
                "SP" sess
FROM            enrollsess
WHERE           enrollsess.yr_offset <= 1
UNION
SELECT          enrollsess.id,
                enrollsess.yr,
                "FA" sess
FROM            enrollsess
WHERE           enrollsess.yr_offset > 1
INTO            TEMP enrollsess2 WITH NO LOG;
```